# Is there a probabilistic difference between these two allocating processes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

9 friends are trying to allocate 27 football teams between them (3 each in total), they want to make the distribution process as fair as possible. Assuming that 1 out of the 27 teams is seen as desirable and the other 26 out of 27 are seen as equal, is there a difference if either:

A) The 1st person draws 3 teams, then the 2nd person draws 3 teams, then the 3rd... etc. Or,

B) Each person draws 1 team consecutively until there are none left?

We were also wondering if there is a higher probability of anyone getting the desirable team, depending on if they go 1st, 2nd, etc... or not?

My attempt to answer this question was as follows:

for process A, I calculated the *probability that the 1st person would not get the desirable team*: $$\frac{26}{27}\cdot\frac{25}{26}\cdot\frac{24}{25}=\frac{8}{9}$$ and then the *probability that the 2nd person would not get the desirable team* = *Probability that the 1st person would get the desirable team* **or** *probability that 1st person would not get the desirable team* **and** *probability that the 2nd person would not get the desirable team*: $$\frac{1}{9} + \frac{8}{9}\cdot (\frac{23}{24}\cdot\frac{22}{23}\cdot\frac{21}{22})=\frac{8}{9}.$$

Since these probabilities coincide it seemed like going first was not an advantage in process A, however, I am not sure if this makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you for your comment. I have added my attempt to the question in the description now :).

Comment: It makes no difference.  One way to see that is, if the teams were on cards laying face down, then whatever elaborate way you allow people to choose the cards, they still have no idea what is on the card, so the probability of getting the best team is equal between them

Comment: how about if the cards had numbers on them 1-27, but the teams were not associated with numbers until after the cards had been chosen, or on the other hand the teams could be secretly associated with numbers, but hidden away in a safe - can any of this make any probability difference?  I don't think it does - even if people see the teams as they are drawn, their probability of getting the top team depends on whether or not it has yet appeared, and how many draws are left